# How to get Notification when "switch User" happen in window7

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, unlock, switch-user

I am building a window application in C# which will notify me when any switch user happen. Right now m using "SessionSwitch" event to get the notification.

```
private void startLisning()
{
        Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionSwitch +=new Microsoft.Win32.SessionSwitchEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionSwitch);
        this.eventHandlerCreated = true;
}

private void SystemEvents_SessionSwitch(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "testtest.txt"), "SwitchUser\t" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);


}
```

But in this case it also sending notification when "UNLOCK" is happen . Which I don't want. 
I only need when any user do switch user in his system my application should get the notification and log it to log file.
It should only log when lock or switchUser happen.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        startLisning();
    }
    private bool eventHandlerCreated;

    private void startLisning()
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionSwitch +=new Microsoft.Win32.SessionSwitchEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionSwitch);
        SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += new SessionSwitchEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionSwitch1);

        this.eventHandlerCreated = true;
    }


    private void SystemEvents_SessionSwitch1(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Reason)
        {
            case SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock:
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "testtest.txt"), "LOCK\t" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
                break;
            case SessionSwitchReason.SessionLogon:
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "testtest.txt"), "LOGIN\t" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
                break;
            case SessionSwitchReason.SessionUnlock:
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "testtest.txt"), "UNLOCK\t" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
                break;
            case SessionSwitchReason.ConsoleConnect:
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "testtest.txt"), "UnlockAfetSwitchUser\t" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
                break;
            case SessionSwitchReason.ConsoleDisconnect:
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "testtest.txt"), "SwitchUser\t" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);

                break;
        }

    }
```

This will notify when "switch user" happen and also notify when the "user resume" . 
'SessionSwitchReason.ConsoleDisconnect' is the event which fire when any switch user happen . This code is tested in windows7 and it working fine.

This code create a "testtest.txt" log file in Appdata folder. U can reach there by using Window+r and search '%appdata%'.

It log notification as below :
1. LOGIN with datetime
2. LOCK with datetime
3. UNLOCK with datetime
4. SWITCH USER with datetime 
5. SWITCH USER RESUME with datetime